# How to find subscript immediately following superscript

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to distinguish between following subscript and superscript cases and based on that i need to display the output. if superscript only appears it would be treated differently, if superscript and subscript follows immediately that would be treated differently

<sup>≠</sup>aaa<sub>M</sub> sample text <sup>≠</sup><sub>M</sub>

```
<article><sup>&ne;</sup>aaa<sub>M</sub> sample text <sup>&ne;</sup><sub>M</sub></article>
```

is there a way to identify this in xpath?

I am trying something like below:

boolean(following-sibling::text()) but need to make two conditions

Comment: How does the XML or HTML input look exactly? `<sup>=</sup>aaa<sub>MM</sub>` would be matchable as e.g. `sup[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()] and following-sibling::node()[2][self::sub]]`.

Answer (score 0):

For the given sample this xpath will return `aaa` (first case)

```
//text()[following-sibling::*[position()=1 and name()="sub"] and preceding-sibling::sup[1]]
```

And this xpath will return `sample text` (second case)

```
//text()[following-sibling::*[1][name()="sup"] and following-sibling::*[2][name()="sub"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of **`<sup>` not followed immediately by `<sub>`** use:

```
sup/following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::sub)]
```

For the case of **`<sup>` that is followed immediately by `<sub>`** use:

```
sup/following-sibling::node()[1][self::sub]
```

Comment: Thanks for very late response. it works for my case. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad this answer was helpful. Please, indicate this helpfulness by accepting the answer and upvoting it.